# What will be connection string for MS Sql 2008 server with instance for the JBoss server and Java

Tags: jdbc, jboss5.x

I have installed SQL sever 2008 locally It has many instance. How do I specify the instance name in jdbc string.

when I access the database using MS SQL studio server name looks like mymachinename\mssqlserver1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you find when you google for "SQLServer JDBC URL": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

> The general form of the connection URL is
>
> jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
>
> where:
>
> - jdbc:sqlserver:// (Required) is known as the sub-protocol and is constant.
> - serverName (Optional) is the address of the server to connect to. This could be a DNS or IP address, or it could be localhost or
>   127.0.0.1 for the local computer. If not specified in the connection URL, the server name must be specified in the properties collection.
> - instanceName (Optional) is the instance to connect to on serverName. If not specified, a connection to the default instance is
>   made.
> - portNumber (Optional) is the port to connect to on serverName. The default is 1433. If you are using the default, you do not have to
>   specify the port, nor its preceding ':', in the URL.
>
> Note:
>
> For optimal connection performance, you should set the portNumber when you connect to a named instance. This will avoid a round trip to
> the server to determine the port number. If both a portNumber and
> instanceName are used, the portNumber will take precedence and the
> instanceName will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I had to first find the port of the instance. One can do this by firing the Query

```
SELECT local_tcp_port
FROM   sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
```

or by logging into the DB Server
[image: MSSQL Instance Port]

And then used the connection string jdbc:sqlserver://db.mssql.company.com\InstanceName:56326;databaseName=DatabaseName;

Answer (score 0):

This is a full URL Example with a differente port and an instance name too

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:PORT;instanceName=INSTANCE;databaseName=DATABASE;", "sa", "PASSWORD);
```